# jenkins loses post-build action settings after restart with plugins based on ruby runtime

Tags: ruby, plugins, jenkins, jruby

Tested with [Yammer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Yammer+Plugin) and [buddycloud Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Buddycloud+Plugin) in Jenkins 2.x. 
Since Yammer and buddycloud plugins depend on jruby based [Ruby Runtime Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ruby+Runtime+Plugin), installing those installs Ruby Runtime first.

As long as I don't restart Jenkins, the plugins work, and their settings persist. But after Jenkins is restarted the Post-Build Action settings on all job's configuration pages are lost and have to be re-entered. The jobs' respective config.xml files retain correct settings, but they seem to have no effect. Is there a fix or a workaround? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a widespread bug with Jenkins plugins Built on JRuby (and employing post-build actions).  I had this same issue with a different plugin that fit this same mold (https://help.rallydev.com/jenkins).   Looks like the issue is logged with Jenkins as Issue #114 (https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins.rb/issues/114).  Still unfixed, but at least there is hope.

Comment: Is there any workaround on this issue while waiting for a fix?